# How to change select menu focus color dynamically using model value - angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to change the focus colour of select menu using model value.

When I try to select "Product Manager". On focusing the value the background colour will be blue. I want to change that background-color dynamically based on $scope.model.webPageSkinColor value.

```
$scope.model.webPageSkinColor = "#7A0834";
$scope.model.webPageSkinColor = "#fff";
$scope.assignedRoles = ["Product Manager", "Student", "Parent", "Engineer"];

    <div class="col-sm-4">
<label class="control-label l_font field-name" for="acode">Select Role *</label>
                             <select class="form-control floating-select" ng-model="model.selectRole" name="selectrole" ng-change="getallassignedRoledetails(model.selectRole)" ng-options="item for item in assignedRoles" required style="width: 100%;" ng-style ="{'background': model.webPageSkin, 'color': model.webPageSkin1}">
                            <option value class selected disabled ng-if="!model.selectRole"></option>
                 </select>


                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator like this :

```
<select class="form-control floating-select" ng-model="model.selectRole" name="selectrole" ng-change="getallassignedRoledetails(model.selectRole)" ng-options="item for item in assignedRoles" required style="width: 100%;" ng-style ="model.selectedRole == 'Product Manager' ? '{"background": model.webPageSkin, "color": model.webPageSkin1}' : '{}'">
```